# Classes of $E=\{ 1,2,3 \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

[image]

- Question $2$: If $E=\{ 1,2,3 \}$ Determine the classes of all $E$ elements of E for each permutation

$E=\{ 1,2,3 \}, \quad  \Omega_{\sigma}(x)=\{ \sigma^{m};m\in \mathbb{Z}  \} $

My Thoughts 
since $x\mathcal{R}_{\sigma} y \iff y\in  \Omega_{\sigma}(x) $ then the classes of E are : $y\in  \Omega_{\sigma}(x)$

Since $E=\{ 1,2,3 \}$ then we have the following permutations :

$\sigma_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}=(1)=(2)=(3)$ if $m\in \mathbb Z$ then  $$\sigma^m(1) \in \{1\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{2\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{3\}.$$
Thus the classes for $\sigma_{1}$ are  $\{1\}$; $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$.

$\sigma_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
2 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=(231)$  if $m\in \mathbb Z$ then $$\sigma^m(1) \in \{2,3,1\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{3,1,2\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{1,2,3\}.$$
Thus the classes for $\sigma_{2}$ are  $\{1,2,3\}$

$\sigma_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
3 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=(321)$ if $m\in \mathbb Z$ then  $$\sigma^m(1) \in \{3,2,1\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{1,3,2\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{2,1,3\}.$$
Thus the classes for $\sigma_{3}$ are $\{3,2,1\}$

$\sigma_{4}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
1 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}(23)$ if $m\in \mathbb Z$ then  $$\sigma^m(1) \in \{1\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{2,3\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{2,3\}.$$
Thus the classes for $\sigma_{4}$ are $\{2,3\}$ et $\{1\}$.

$\sigma_{5}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
3 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=(13)$ if $m\in \mathbb Z$ then  $$\sigma^m(1) \in \{1,3\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{2\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{1,3\}.$$
Thus the classes for $\sigma_{5}$ are  sont $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2\}$.

$\sigma_{6}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3  \\
2 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}=(12)$  if $m\in \mathbb Z$ then  $$\sigma^m(1) \in \{1,2\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{1,2\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{3\}.$$
Thus the classes for $\sigma_{6}$ are  $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$.

Comment: It can be more informative to write $(1 \, 2)$ for $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eric Towers wrote in a comment, it would be helpful to write $(12)$ instead of $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix}$. In this permutation, the element $3$ is fixed.

Taking the above permutation as an example (let's call it $\sigma$), the question wants you to observe that if $m\in \mathbb Z$, then
$$\sigma^m(1) \in \{1,2\},\\ \sigma^m(2) \in \{1,2\},\\ \sigma^m(3) \in \{3\}.$$

Thus the classes for $\sigma$ are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$. Do you see how this relates to @Eric Towers's comment?

Comment: check my update please

Comment: @Educ Almost right: keep in mind that the classes are sets, so for example $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{2,3,1\}$ are exactly the same thing and should not be considered as separate classes.

Comment: check again please

Comment: @Educ Ça y est! Looks good to me.